# Is there a structure with these properties?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, logic, predicate-logic

I'm looking for a structure which holds these properties:

For some `domain`,  (eg. `N,R, sets` or whatever), there is a predicate `P(x,y)`:

for all `x` from domain there is not `y` such that `P(x,y)`

`AND` either a) or b) is valid but not both:

a) there exists `y` such that for all `x` `P(y,x)`

```
OR
```

b) for all `x` there exists `y` such that `P(y,x)`

I've tried many `P(x,y)`, for example `P(x,y)` `=> x mod y = 0` etc. but still I'm not able to find such structure.

Could you help me? Is there some?

EDIT: Repaired f to P - predicate, Predicate could be for example `P(x,y)=> x mod y = 0`

Comment: What do you mean by "for all x from domain there is not y such that f(x,y)"? If $f$ is a binary function in a structure then it should be defined on all binary tuples in that structure. Do you actually just want a formula f(x,y) in some structure which satisfy your properties?

Comment: @OveAhlman I mean something like this: For all X from D, there is not Y such that f(x,y) - let's set f(x,y) => x/y = 2 - for example for number 1 is not any number from N such that 1/number = 2 /////// EDIT: I've repaired the question changing f to P (predicate)

Comment: Why don't you just use a predicate which is never valid? Such as $P(x,y)$ as $x=y \wedge x\neq x$? As your question is formulated right now this is ans answer, so I guess there is something wrong with the question.

Comment: Because I need this predicate to be valid in one of these two: a)there exists some y such that for this y and all x from domain P(y,x) b) for all x there exists some y: P(y,x)

Comment: But you say "either a) or b) is not valid". Do you acutally mean that one of a) and b) should be true and one of a) or b) should be false?

Comment: @OveAhlman Yes Ove, sorry for bad explanation of the problem. One of them should be True and one of them should be False.

Answer (score 0):

The "first statement" I interpret as  $\forall x\exists y \neg P(x,y)$ (as if we interpret it as you have written $\forall x\neg\exists y P(x,y)$ then P needs to be the empty relation).

As your formulation is vague and weird I have two choices of answers for you:

*If I assume that $a)$ is $\exists y\forall x P(x,y)$ and $b)$ is $\forall x\exists y P(x,y)$. In this case let our structure have domain the natural numbers and say that $P(a,b)$ hold if ($a=0$ and $b=0$) or ($b=1$ and $a\neq 0$)
In this case $a)$ is not satisfied but both $b)$ and the first statement is satisfied.

*On the other hand If we interpret your statement $a)$ as $\exists y \forall x P(y,x)$ and $b)$ as $\forall x \exists y P(y,x)$ then the negation of $a)$ will be equivalent with $\forall y\exists x \neg P(y,x)$ i.e. the first statement. Thus we can't have $a)$ to be true, hence $b)$ needs to be true. For this to be satisfied we may though just choose the opposite structure of what we previously did i.e. let P(a,b) hold if $a=0$ and $b=0$ or $b\neq 0$ and $a=1$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Had a negation to much. Now edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**, there isn't.

Consider :

> 1) $\forall x \lnot \exists y P(x,y)$
>
> 2a) $\exists y \forall x P(y,x)$
>
> 2b) $\forall x \exists y P(y,x)$.

**Case I** : consider 2a) and let $a$ such that : $\forall x P(a,x)$. By $\forall$-E we have : $P(a,a)$.

But from 1) we get the equivalent : $\forall x \forall y \lnot P(x,y)$, and thus : $\lnot P(a,a)$. *Contradiction !*

**Case II** : consider 2b), and assume more than one element in the domain (the case with only one element is like I); we have : $P(b,a)$, but again from 1) we get $\lnot P(b,a)$. *Contradiction !*